# Merge pandas dataframe on time and another column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two pandas dataframes that I'm trying to combine into a single dataframe.  Here's how I set them up:

```
a = {'date':['1/1/2015 00:00','1/1/2015 00:15','1/1/2015 00:30'], 'num':[1,2,3]}
b = {'date':['1/1/2015 01:15','1/1/2015 01:30','1/1/2015 01:45'], 'num':[4,5,6]}

dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)

dfa['date'] = dfa['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
dfb['date'] = dfb['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

I then find the `earliest` and `latest` time stamps from each, and create a new dataframe that starts as just a `date` series:

```
earliest = min(dfa['date'].min(), dfb['date'].min())
latest = max(dfa['date'].max(), dfb['date'].max())

date_range = pd.date_range(earliest, latest, freq='15min')

dfd = pd.DataFrame({'date':date_range})
```

I then want to merge them all into a single dataframe with `dfd` being the base as it will contain all of the proper time stamps.  So I merge `dfd` and `dfa` and all is good:

```
dfd = pd.merge(dfd, dfa, how = 'outer', on = 'date')
```

However, when I merge it with `dfb` the `date` series gets screwy and I can't figure out why.

```
dfd = pd.merge(dfd, dfb, how = 'outer', on = ['date','num'])
```

...yields:

```
                  date  num
0  2015-01-01 00:00:00  1.0
1  2015-01-01 00:15:00  2.0
2  2015-01-01 00:30:00  3.0
3  2015-01-01 00:45:00  NaN
4  2015-01-01 01:00:00  NaN
5  2015-01-01 01:15:00  NaN
6  2015-01-01 01:30:00  NaN
7  2015-01-01 01:45:00  NaN
8  2015-01-01 01:15:00  4.0
9  2015-01-01 01:30:00  5.0
10 2015-01-01 01:45:00  6.0
```

Where I would expect `4.0` to fill in the `2015-01-01 01:15:00` time slot, etc. and not create new rows.

Or if I try:

```
dfd = pd.merge(dfd, dfb, how = 'outer', on = 'date')
```

I get:

```
                 date  num_x  num_y
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00    1.0    NaN
1 2015-01-01 00:15:00    2.0    NaN
2 2015-01-01 00:30:00    3.0    NaN
3 2015-01-01 00:45:00    NaN    NaN
4 2015-01-01 01:00:00    NaN    NaN
5 2015-01-01 01:15:00    NaN    4.0
6 2015-01-01 01:30:00    NaN    5.0
7 2015-01-01 01:45:00    NaN    6.0
```

which is also not what I want (just want a single `num` column).  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems like `merge()` is filling in the missing datetimes (i.e. You can't jump from 00:30:00 to 01:15:00). I say just delete the rows manually, using conditional indices and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dfa.set_index('date').combine_first(dfb.set_index('date')) \
    .asfreq('15T').reset_index()

                 date    num
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00 1.0000
1 2015-01-01 00:15:00   2.00
2 2015-01-01 00:30:00   3.00
3 2015-01-01 00:45:00    nan
4 2015-01-01 01:00:00    nan
5 2015-01-01 01:15:00   4.00
6 2015-01-01 01:30:00   5.00
7 2015-01-01 01:45:00   6.00
```

---

another solution

```
dfa.append(dfb).set_index('date').asfreq('15T').reset_index()
```

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared but I updated my question, I want a single `num` column.

Comment: @piRSquared Are you on jupyter notebook? How come you got such a big table before?

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi I don't know, that't why I took it off.  It was ridiculous looking.  I'm on a mac and I think I tweaked my screenshot somehow.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Gotta love a one-liner.  Thanks @piRSquared.

Comment: @pshep123 just gave you a shorter one.

Comment: I'm getting an error on your second solution: `cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: @pshep123 bah! yeah, I'm assuming the dates didn't overlap.

Comment: @pshep123 that brings up a good question.  what do you want to do if they do overlap?

Comment: @piRSquared - your solution actually works fine with the data set provided in my question, so my bad.  I was playing around with overlapping time stamps as well and... the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131115/discussion-between-pshep123-and-pirsquared).

Answer (score 1):

Merge dfa and dfb first:

```
d = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, on=['date','num'], how='outer')
```

Then combine the result with dfd as you defined:

```
result = pd.merge(d, dfd, on='date', how='outer')
print result.sort('date')
```

Output:

```
                 date  num
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00  1.0
1 2015-01-01 00:15:00  2.0
2 2015-01-01 00:30:00  3.0
6 2015-01-01 00:45:00  NaN
7 2015-01-01 01:00:00  NaN
3 2015-01-01 01:15:00  4.0
4 2015-01-01 01:30:00  5.0
5 2015-01-01 01:45:00  6.0
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't fill the missing time stamps.

Comment: yes, sorry that I misunderstood about missing data first, I edit my answer now

Comment: Much appreciated @lingpingta.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a = {'date':['1/1/2015 00:00','1/1/2015 00:15','1/1/2015 00:30'], 'num':[1,2,3]}
b = {'date':['1/1/2015 01:15','1/1/2015 01:30','1/1/2015 01:45'], 'num':[4,5,6]}

dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)

dfa['date'] = dfa['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
dfb['date'] = dfb['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

earliest = min(dfa['date'].min(), dfb['date'].min())
latest = max(dfa['date'].max(), dfb['date'].max())

date_range = pd.date_range(earliest, latest, freq='15min')

dfd = pd.DataFrame({'date':date_range})


df_dates = pd.merge(dfa, dfb, how = 'outer')
df_final = pd.merge(dfd, df_dates, how = 'outer')

df_final
```