# Pandas merge error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I recently asked a question
[Merge pandas dataframe on time and another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41255278/merge-pandas-dataframe-on-time-and-another-column)
about merging dataframes and got a superb, one-line, answer that worked perfectly with my test data.  However, when I tried to put it into my actual data I got the following error:

`cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Here's some of the code from that question (with a minor change to show overlapping timestamps):

```
a = {'date':['1/1/2015 00:00','1/1/2015 00:15','1/1/2015 00:30'], 'num':[1,2,3]}
b = {'date':['1/1/2015 00:15','1/1/2015 00:30','1/1/2015 00:45'], 'num':[4,5,6]}

dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)

dfa['date'] = dfa['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
dfb['date'] = dfb['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

and the solution:

```
dfa.set_index('date').combine_first(dfb.set_index('date')).asfreq('15T').reset_index()
```

The above code (with simple data) works like a charm, but if anyone knows what might be going wrong with my code in production, please let me know.  Thanks.

And yes, there are similar questions on SO, but I haven't found any that deal with the fact that there will inherently be duplicates in the indices and I want one to overwrite the other.

Comment: do you have duplicate dates with `dfa` by itself?  Or `dfb` by itself?  If so, do you want to keep the first one?

Comment: @piRSquared - I don't think there are duplicates within `dfa` or `dfb` but can check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is your data have duplicates in `name` in `dfa` or `dfb` (maybe both), you can simulate it by sample:

```
a = {'date':['1/1/2015 00:00','1/1/2015 00:00','1/1/2015 00:30'], 'num':[1,2,3]}
b = {'date':['1/1/2015 00:15','1/1/2015 00:30','1/1/2015 00:45'], 'num':[4,5,6]}

dfa = pd.DataFrame(a)
dfb = pd.DataFrame(b)

dfa['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfa['date'])
dfb['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dfb['date'])

print (dfa)
                 date  num
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00    1
1 2015-01-01 00:00:00    2
2 2015-01-01 00:30:00    3
```

And solution is remove duplicates:

```
#keep first duplicates, by default
dfa = dfa.drop_duplicates('date')
print (dfa)
                 date  num
0 2015-01-01 00:00:00    1
2 2015-01-01 00:30:00    3

#keep last duplicates
dfa = dfa.drop_duplicates('date', keep='last')
print (dfa)
                 date  num
1 2015-01-01 00:00:00    2
2 2015-01-01 00:30:00    3
```

Comment: You're showing a duplicate in `a` where I wasn't.  But you may be on to something.  I'll have to dig into the data.  Thanks.

Comment: You can esy test it by `print (dfa.date.unique())


print (dfb.date.unique())
`

Comment: I look at it, but numpy is hard for me (I have no idea why is different timings), I think you can wait for some guru like divakar. ;)